# Spring\Spring Boot: Is there a need for a custom validator?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Suppose I have this controller mapping function:

```
@GetMapping("/result")
public Stats result(@RequestParam Integer homeId, @RequestParam Integer awayId)
        throws MissingTeamException, InvalidTeamIdExcpetion {

    //Validation starts here
    int numOfAvailableTeams = teamResource.retrieveAllTeams().size();
    
    if( homeId < 0 || homeId >= numOfAvailableTeams)
            throw new InvalidTeamIdExcpetion(homeId);

    if(awayId < 0 || awayId >= numOfAvailableTeams)
            throw new InvalidTeamIdExcpetion(awayId);
    //end of validation

    return generateResult(homeId, awayId);
}
```

You can see that I am validating the home and away ids.

Can I do a it in a cleaner way apart of creating a custom validator class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally in every case logic should be wrote in service class (marked by `@Service`), not in controller. So, you can create a service class with method `validating()` with arguments needed to validate. Service example:

```java
@Service
public class YourService {

    //This variable and constructor are optional because I didn't see your whole code.
    //But if you will to create TeamResource field in service, Spring Boot will automatically
    //inject teamResource if you have suitable Bean.
    private TeamResource teamResource;

    public YourService(TeamResource teamResource) {
        this.teamResource = teamResource;
    }

    public TypeOfMethodGenerateResult validate(Integer homeId, Integer awayId) {

        int numOfAvailableTeams = teamResource.retrieveAllTeams().size();

        if (homeId < 0 || homeId >= numOfAvailableTeams)
            throw new InvalidTeamIdExcpetion(homeId);

        if(awayId < 0 || awayId >= numOfAvailableTeams)
            throw new InvalidTeamIdExcpetion(awayId);

        return generateResult(homeId, awayId);
    }
}
```

And controller:

```java
//Autoinject like in service.
private YourService yourService;

public YourService(YourService yourService) {
    this.yourService = yourService;
}

@GetMapping("/result")
public Stats result(@RequestParam Integer homeId, @RequestParam Integer awayId)
        throws MissingTeamException, InvalidTeamIdExcpetion {

    return yourService.validate(homeId, awayId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks fr3ddie. Thank you for the tip for creating a service class. But I see you still recommend to ignore using a custom validator and leave the validation in the service class, right?

Comment: Yes, but what custom validator do you mean? Something like in `Nakul Goyal's` example? Validtion between brackets in method?

Comment: I mean like in the example here: https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/#implementing-a-custom-validator. I just want to learn the best practice in such a case..

Comment: Interesting issue. I must to learn myself about things from this article.

Comment: I finally decided to rely on the example here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator. Thank you for your effort :)

Answer (score 0):

To validate @RequestParam you can use **@Valid** and **@Validated** annotations.

```
@GetMapping("/result")
    public String result(@RequestParam @Valid @Size(min = 1) Integer homeId,
            @RequestParam @Valid @Size(min = 1) Integer awayId)
```

*Use **@Validated** over the Class itself.*

**Imports for reference:**

> import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
>
> import javax.validation.Valid;
>
> import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

Comment: Thanks Nakul. But your example validates only min value. What about the max value?

Comment: `@Size(max = 1)` and `@Size(min = 1, max = 4)`  are available too.

Comment: Yes, but the max is not a fixed number. It is being calculated based on db state.

Comment: Just so changing annotation value dynamically is not possible :/ So only way that I see is create that service like in my answer.

Comment: @dushkin In annotations like Size you can use a constant values only. If you have a dynamic value to validate, then you must need to create your own validator. I specified in my answers also that this is just to validate the RequestParam or such incoming data at parameter level itself.